# Rails Actionmailer - Find original header in bounceback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, runner, email-bounces

I've set up a forwarder through cpanel called 'eblast-bounceback@mydomain.com' which pipes to a runner (i.e., look up any tutorial on receiving emails through rails).  This part works just fine - I can tell that the script is running because I've set it to use the logger.  The problem I'm having is being able to find my custom header "X-Subscriber-Id: " within the bounceback email.  Is there a way to access the raw email data so I can just do a regex search or do I have to do this in a more complicated way?

On another note, is it wise to automatically remove the email from the database if I get a bounceback or is there some sort of addition steps I need to take to avoid malicious intent?

EDIT: Posted Code...

```
def receive(email)
    # email.body doesn't work...how do I search for this?  I know it's in the email...
    account = /X\-Subscriber\-Id: (.*)/.match(email.body)[1].split("|") rescue nil
    # If we've found the account info
    logger.info "Nil?: #{account.nil?}"
    if !account.nil?
        id, private_id = account[0].to_i, account[1]
        if @subscriber = Subscriber.find_by_id(id)
            @subscriber.update_attribute(:bouncebacks, @subscriber.bouncebacks.to_i + 1)
            logger.info "Faulty Account: #{@subscriber.email}"
        end
    else
            # This is where we email the admin in case of failure to find an account (manual removal from database)
            # This section is incomplete at this time
        @from = "My Site <admin@mysite.com>"
        @recipients = "admin@mysite.com"
        @subject = "Bounceback could not be processed"
        #@body = email.body -- What do I put here to simply re-send the email?
    end
end
```

Comment: No its not wise at all to remove on a delivery failure, you could have someones mail server who is running maintenance or any number or conditions that would trigger your system.

Comment: I actually have it set up so that it adds 1 to a running 'bounceback count'.  When it gets to 3 it removes the email from the database.  Every two months each bounceback is reduced by 1.

Comment: I guess that's an ok solution, is it worth the hassle though? Also, it might be helpful if you post the code that you are using now to receive the emails

Comment: Nevermind, turns out a simple Email.to_s does the trick just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used email.to_s instead of email.body.